# ADAL for Cordova - Assistance Getting Started

Tags: cordova-plugins, adal

Hello: I'm trying to get started with the ADAL plug-in for Cordova. Having used the native libraries a few times, I thought this would be pretty straightforward but I ran into a bit of an issue.

First of all my environment is VS2017, and the plugin is ADAL for Cordova 0.10.1.

I've created what I believe is the most simplistic example of a connection, using my own client application specifics and the ones provided in their sample online (which is) included below. My authentication looks like:

```
function authenticate(authCompletedCallback, errorCallback) {

var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
    redirectUri = "http://localhost:4400",
    resourceUri = "https://graph.windows.net",
    clientId = "a5d92493-ae5a-4a9f-bcbf-9f1d354067d3";

var authContext = new Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext(authority);
authContext.acquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientId, redirectUri).then(authCompletedCallback, errorCallback);
```

This is then called in onDeviceReady();

acquireTokenAsync is called but doesn't appear to return either success or failure and a quick Fiddler trace doesn't appear to show the call which makes me wonder if it is not a configuration issue with Cordova to begin with.

I have commented out the Content-Security-Policy metatag with similar results.

Thank you in advance for any guidance!

**Edit**

Okay, perhaps this is helpful. I noticed that on the Cordova Plugin Simulation tab (I am trying to run this in the simulator in Chrome). I am seeing a dialog box with error:

> There is no handler for the following exec call:
>
> ADALProxy.acquireTokenAsync(...

Also, seems to work on a connected Android Device, just not in the local Simulator

Comment: You should start with [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-cordova) and if this does not work, please update the info in this question

Comment: Thanks Andre - I have followed those steps (unless I overlooked something) BEFORE posting the original question. As you can see in the code snippet and, as I allude to, the auth, redirect Uri, etc. are from the article in question.

Answer (score 0):

The plug-in for Cordova doesn't support to run on the browser platform. When we developer an Cordova app and want to test on the browser platform, we have to ensure that the app depends on support the browser platform.

For the [ADAL plug-in for Cordova](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova) support the platform:

> Android (OS 4.0.3 and higher)
>
> iOS Windows (Windows 8.0, Windows 8.1,
>
> Windows 10 and Windows Phone 8.1)

And for other kinds of plug-in you can check it via you the [Cordova plug-in](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=camera&platforms=cordova-browser).